# How to create a global message rather than a return redirect message, after import complete

Tags: laravel, messaging

I have an import function that returns a message summarizing the import results upon completion. It is currently a return redirect message that thus displays the message in the import view when the import is finished.

```
  $rows = $counter;
  $updates = count($update);
  $table = Str::plural($modelName);

  Storage::delete('csv_import/' . $filename);

  $redirect = $request->input('redirect', false);

  return redirect()->to($redirect)->with('message', trans(($updates > 0 ? 'global.app_imported_rows_to_table_with_updates' : 'global.app_imported_rows_to_table'),
            ['rows' => $rows, 'updates' => $updates, 'table' => $table]
```

The import is done by a job in the background enabling a user to move around the app doing different things while the import completes. The issue is that the return message as it is currently, displays the message in the import page view but frequently the user is elsewhere in the app when the import completes and thus does not get to see the message.

How might one be able to refactor this so that the message, upon import completion, is displayed globally in any view the user might be on when the import finishes?

Comment: How can a "job in the background" return an HTTP redirect response to the user?

Comment: The concept you're describing is [broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a notification seen throughout your application after the import is done. You need to set up three things.

First is a job and queue. What is will do. When the import process is starting it will disrupt your main thread preventing your users to navigate to other pages or doing other actions. Import is a heavy process, you know. By running your import to a queue, you will somehow have a multi-thread scenario.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues

Second, set up a pusher or anything that will broadcast an event to your front-end to listen. For example...

You want to import 10k contacts and you run it in the queue. So it will take minutes to finish depending on the process under the hood. And in your job's logic, you will need to call a broadcast event to notify your front-end that the import process is done.

```
broadcast(new SomeEvent());
```

And in your front-end, you have to listen to that event and do something like you know. Notify the user?

[Broadcast Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#listening-for-notifications)

And lastly, if you want to notify users regardless of which page they are on in your app, you need to set up something, like probably in Vue, somewhere in your app.js a notifiable to notify your users that their import is done.

Comment: Thank you for the information, this functionality is exactly what I am looking for. Your comment and explanation was quite helpful.